# Error after validation by email

Tags: 6, users

I have the following problem with drupal 6 and I am using the Login Tobogan module.  When an user creates a new account in Drupal, the user receives the respective email.  When the users click in the link for validate the account, the account is validated but appears the next error:

```
Unable to send e-mail. Please contact the site administrator if the problem persists.
You have successfully validated your e-mail address.
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have disabled the Login Tobogan and I have enabled again the Login Tobogan again and the error was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem once, but then realized that it happened for wrong email configuration. For my case, it was the server restricted gmail mail address to send emails from the servers. So, I changed the site email address something to mymail@mydomain.com & it worked.

If you're using smtp module, then please check all other settings on smtp page as well, specially web-server username& passwords to match your hosting mailbox password.

Send a testing emails & enabling debug option will help you to understand better if other problems were there.

Hope now you can use LoginToboggan & smtp both without that problem :)